# java, xenserver, does anybody knows how to run a command on a virtual machine?

Tags: java, virtual-machine

i'm using XenServer, i'm connecting the pool, getting the list of all VM.
now i need to loging to the VM.
and to execute an exe file on all VM.
anyone has any idea ?

Thank you!

```
connection = new Connection(url);
Session.loginWithPassword(connection, userName, Password, APIVersion.latest().toString());


Map<VM, VM.Record> vms = VM.getAllRecords(connection);
for (VM.Record record : vms.values()){
    if (!record.isATemplate){
        // now i need somehow to connect with the VM username and password
        // now i need to run an exe file.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, XenServer API doesn't provide any api that can execute commands in VM. And IMHO, a VMM like XenServer or VMware should not have the right to execute commands in any VM that it hosts. So , why not get the ip of all the vm and use some ssh libraries to execute the commands ?

Answer (score 0):

Use sshj's `Session.exec()` to execute remote commands via ssh. There's [an example of doing this in the Github repo](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/blob/master/src/main/java/examples/Exec.java).